# Can't getting value from Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am facing an issue with getting a value from Web.config.

Here is my web.config code which contains **Key**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="Email" value="myname@mydomain.com" />
```

i want email key value, i am writing,

```
  string From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString();
```

but its giving me error **"Object reference is not set to an instance of an object"**

My other web.config declarations are:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="***" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" userName="myname@mydomain.com" password="mypassword" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net for help on `NullReferenceException`s

Comment: Well is it actually looking to the config file you posted (i guess not) **Or** is it throwing error only for `Email` ?

Comment: Looks strange. Are you sure that this row is causing the exception? Or perhaps this code is called from different project than the one where web.config resides? Did you try looking at ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"] value in debug?

Comment: I agree make sure that your code is pointing to correct place . Code looks fine . In debug mode check for AppSettings values

Comment: @AlexanderTsvetkov Yes i have looked at its values but it is only showing 2 Keys 
[0] ClientValidationEnabled 
[1] UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled



3rd Email key is not even in the debugging.

Comment: If you are working with MVC, then you will observer that there will be two web.config files, one in View directory and the second one in you project root dircetory. Make sure you have these values in the one that is in root directory of you project.

Comment: @umair.ali

Got your point
Thanks i resolved it :)

Comment: Another note, you do not have to call `.ToString()` on `AppSettings["key"]`. It is already a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your start up project is set correctly. If you're running this from a separate project (i.e. in a test), it won't be looking at that Web.config but its own Web/App.config file.